# Is it okay to save thumbnail version in file system? what is the common practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, asp.net-web-api

I have a web application I'm building up, where in one of the module, I let the users to upload images which are later shown in a slider with thumbnails on the bottom.

My question is, should I save the thumbnail version in the file system or is it better to create an API that accepts the path to the image and returns a resized version with desired content type?

Saving the thumbnail gives an additional overhead of maintaining additional files. But if I create a WebAPI to resize the image on demand, I'm worried, if it will affect the performance as it involves image processing.

How would you handle this situation?

Comment: You've covered 2 reasonable approaches with both pro and cons. It is really up to you to decide (measure if needed) which one works for your case.

Comment: Save the image + thumbnail on upload. Then prefix/suffix the thumbnails to make file management a bit easier. When you need to load a thumbnail version of a image you could do something like "thumb_myimage.png". Either way is fine, it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's pretty common practice to resize images to all the different thumbnail sizes you will need and save them to some data store.  It will probably make very little difference in terms of how much total storage you will need (since you're storing the biggest picture either way) and the performance gain is well worth it.

At my company, we save about 20 different thumbnail sizes for each photo and save them all to Amazon S3 where storage is dirt cheap and they have a fast content delivery network to make page loads lightning fast.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/), an HttpModule that could resize on-the-fly and cache your thumbnails without an extra code. You need to download it to the \bin, [setup a web.config](http://imageresizing.net/docs/install/web-config) and you will be able to resize images using e.g. [URL API](http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics) as

```
<img src="large.jpg?width=100" />
```

Since you are concerned about performance, setup a [DiskCache feature](http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics) and let to cache resized images to disk.